# Using File Mapping to read data from file

Tags: c++, api

I want to read data from a file (.txt) and push into Edit box.
I'm writing C++ with pure API.

```
HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPVOID pMemory;
```

and

```
case IDM_OPEN:
            hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)szFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, NULL);
            hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
            pMemory = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0,0,0);
            FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
            SendMessage(hWndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(LPCWSTR)pMemory);
            MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)pMemory, L"Caption", MB_OK);
            UnmapViewOfFile(pMemory);
            CloseHandle(hMapFile);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            break;
```

Result: Blank, nothing in Edit box

I search some page but not solved.

When I try debug by set breakpoint like this image:

http://i8.upanh.com/2013/1103/02//57993893.untitled.png

(Sorry I can't post image)

hFile is 0xffffffff, so I think error is CreateFile, but I don't understand !!

Please help me solve this. Thanks !!!

Comment: Which line is it failing on?  What are the results CreateFile, CreateFileMapping, and MapViewOfFile.  It's likely that one of them is failing.  You should be checking there return values for errors in your code.

Comment: And you better hope that file has a terminating NUL-char (which I'm kinda doubting at this juncture).

Comment: From the `CreateFile` documentation: `If the function fails, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.`

Comment: @ThùyDương: You are missing a lot of error handling. Once you do get `CreateFile()` working, keep in mind that the mapping will operate on bytes, so `(LPCWSTR)pMemory` will work properly only if the file contents are UTF-16 encoded and null-terminated. And `WM_SETTEXT` will only work with UTF-16 text if your program is compiled for Unicode and `hWndEdit` is a Unicode window. That is a lot of assumptions to make. This is not very good programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)szFileName,....
```

Why the cast to LPCWSTR? If you need that cast you are doing something wrong. Investigate each step with a debugger to learn more about what is wrong.

Comment: +1 I likewise suspect this is being compiled with Unicode settings enabled, and `szFileName` is a `char` buffer, with the aforementioned cast attempting to rectify the problem. Further, the file itself is highly likely also narrow characters, meaning even if the OP fixes this they have another equally annoying problem.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: Thanks to your recommend, I edited:
wchar_t* szFileName = 0;
szFileName = L"abc.txt";
hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, NULL);
But hFile value in debugger when execute this line still: 0xffffffff.
What error ???

Comment: @ThùyDương: You need to call `GetLastError()` to find out why it fails. Chances are, either the file does not exist anywhere on the current search path (since you are specifying a **relative** path to the .txt file), or the file is already open by something else and is not sharing access to the file.